# The two label overlap in a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am new for IOS development , and I try to use `UIcollectionView` to show the photo.

I am not using `storyboard`.

I create a `xib file` call `AITFileCell_grid.xib` , and add a `Collection View Cell` like the following picture.

[image]

The view show show the **icon** , **file name** and **file size** in `collectionViewCell`.

The **file name** is long , so **set the line of file name to 2**

When I run the App. The text of **file name** and **file size** are overlap like the following picture.

[image]

**How should I modify can make **file name** and **file size** non-overlapping ?**

What reason causing this condition happened ?

Comment: You need to do (and learn) a few things so search for some existing tutorials: https://www.google.com/search?q=autolayout+dynamic+collection+view+cell

Comment: You know the reason that is your file name is too long so it is breaking into 2 lines. So you could simply giver bigger width to that UILabel or place the size UILabel little below so as to avoid overlapping. Also you could go to UILabel and change some features of line wrap.

Comment: simply get the function from stack overflow for counting number of line of label, check for the name label if it one line or two line accordingly set dynamic y position of size label. and increase the size of UICollectionViewCell.

Comment: @AshwinMangrulkar that's exactly why Auto-layout exists ;)

Comment: I have try to use auto-layout , I set `file size` for **leading space** to `file name` , and set the `file size` and the `file name` for **equal width** to `imageView`. But it is the same...

Answer (score 1):

Because you have set the **file name** label to be a 2-liner it displays in 2 lines if its text is long enough. **File size** label position is static so it doesn't move down in this cases.

You have multiple choices.

- you can either make `UICollectionViewCell` bigger so that the **filename** can take two lines and put the **file size** label under;
- you can also make **filename** label scale its font's size if it becomes longer than 1 line and leave **file size** label as it is;
- you can also truncate **filename** label if it becomes longer than 1 line (in case you don't need full filename);
- you can make use of auto-layout (as @Wain suggested) and dynamically resize and position both labels based on their text sizes.

Comment: I have try to use auto-layout , I set `file size` for **leading space** to `file name` , and set the `file size` and the `file name` for **equal width** to `imageView`. But it is the same...

Comment: @Wun what you need is an ``Vertical Space`` (Top) constraint from **file size** label to **file name** label instead of leading.

Comment: @Wun please go through this guides:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html
http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2